# Will Ubuntu 16.04.6 updates ever include a version of Apache newer than 2.4.18?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, update

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS and am fully up to date with apt update and apt upgrade.

This still leaves me at Apache 2.4.18 which has some known security issues and the IT security guys are complaining.

So, will the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS upgrades ever include a newer, more secure version of Apache?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

If you are up to date then you are **not** running (stock) 2.4.18, you are running **2.4.18-2ubuntu3.13**, which is a newer, more secure version.

Ask your "IT security" guys if they, or the brain-dead security tools they are using, understand the difference.

Here are the changes: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.13/changelog

Also ask them if these "known security issues" apply to your environment.

(Yes, there is some heat in this response.)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I've passed it on. Hopefully this will make them happy.